# regex_replace not working during cin

Tags: c++, regex, space

```
string input("Have a *great* day");
regex re("(.*)[*](.+?)[*](.*)");    

string output;
cin >> input; //Doesn't work
//output = regex_replace(input, re, "$1<p>$2</p>$3");
regex_replace(back_inserter(output), input.begin(), input.end(), re, "$1<p>$2</p>$3");
cout << output << endl;
```

When I run it without cin, I get what I expect:
"Have a <great> day"

However, when I use cin and type in the same exact string as input, I get:
"Have"

The expression ends as soon as a space is encountered

What's going on?

Comment: Use `std::getline` instead of `cin >> input`.

Comment: `input` contains `"Have"`; nothing to do with your regex.

Answer (score 2):

As `cin>>input` extract a single word not the entire sentence, your `input` get only  `Have` of your entire word `just Have a *great* day` that reflects your output. Just replace `cin>>input` with

```
getline(cin, input);
```

which take an entire line.